# Perl replace multiple strings in a file

Tags: arrays, perl, replace

I'm having trouble repleacing a set of strings in a file with something else. I already checked on stackoverflow and on other sites but something is missing.
I have a file that contains the following:

```
  12 [ fillcolor="#62cb62", fontcolor="#ffffff", label="HealthStatus 12", shape=hexagon ]
  520 [ fillcolor="#ffc0cb", fontcolor="#000000", label="A-SYNT 520", shape=parallelogram ]
  521 [ fillcolor="#ffc0cb", fontcolor="#000000", label="A-CONF 521", shape=parallelogram ]
  522 [ fillcolor="#ffc0cb", fontcolor="#000000", label="A-SAFE 522", shape=parallelogram ]

  12 -> 522 [ color="#000000" ]
  12 -> 521 [ color="#000000" ]
  12 -> 520 [ color="#000000" ]
```

I want to replace

```
12 [ with 12 HealthStatus [
520 [ with 520 A-SYNT [
521 [ with 521 A-CONF [
522 [ with 522 A-SAFE [
12 -> with 12 HealthStatus ->
```

I already have in an array the numbers and the strings and I save them in the variables $proxyid and $proxyname .

Here's the code I'm using

```
rename($GVFILE, $GVFILE.'.bak');

open(OUT, '>'.$GVFILE) or die $!;
print_log ($IL, "## proxystack $#proxy_stack");
open(IN, '<'.$GVFILE.'.bak') or die $!;
for (my $cursor = 0; $cursor <= $#proxy_stack; $cursor++) {

  $proxy_length = 0;
  $proxyid = $proxy_stack[$cursor];
  $proxyname = $proxy_stack[$cursor]{'name'};
  print_log ($IL, "## debug $proxyid $proxyname");
  print_log ($IL, "## debug cursor $cursor");
  while(<IN>)
  {    
      $_ =~ s/$proxyid \[/$proxyid $proxyname \[/g;
      $_ =~ s/$proxyid -\>/$proxyid $proxyname -\>/g;
      print OUT $_;
  }
  
  
}
close(IN);
close(OUT);
```

I'm sure I have everything in $proxy_stack since I'm printing it and I get all the elements I expect but  only the first replacement is performed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are basically doing your loops in the wrong order: you are looping on `@proxy_stack` and then on `<IN>`, but you should be doing the opposite. Thus, what is happening is that in the first iteration of `for (my $cursor = 0; $cursor <= $#proxy_stack; $cursor++)`, the while loop `while(<IN>)` reads the whole file, and performs the substitution for the first element of `@proxy_stack`. Then, it moves on to the second iteration of the for loop, but you've reached the end of `IN`, and thus the `while(<IN>)` loop doesn't loop at all.

This will work:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $GVFILE = "t.txt";
rename $GVFILE, "$GVFILE.bak";

open my $out, '>', $GVFILE or die $!;
open my $in, '<', "$GVFILE.bak" or die $!;

my %proxies = ('12' => 'HealthStatus',
               '520' => 'A-SYNT',
               '521' => 'A-CONF',
               '522' => 'A-SAFE');

while (<$in>) {
    for my $proxy (keys %proxies) {
        s/(\Q$proxy\E) (\[|->)/$1 $proxies{$1} $2/g;
    }
    print $out $_;
}
```

I've made a few modifications:

- I've added `use strict` and `use warnings`, which **you should always do**. (and I've declared variables with `my`, which you should always do as well, but you probably don't have to think too much about it, as `strict` will remind you if you forget)
- I used 3-argument `open` (as you should always do).
- I used lexical file-handles instead of global ones (you should never use global file handles).
- I've used a hashmap instead of your `@proxy_stack` array. This seemed simpler, but you might have a legitimate reason to use an array, in which case I'm sure you'll be able to modify my code to use an array instead.
- I used a `foreach` loop to iterate over `%proxies` (which corresponds to `@proxy_stack` in your code). It's more idiomatic, and more concise.

Depending on you actual code, this might seem a bit simpler and more efficient (because the regex engines should optimize `|` in the regex):

```
my %proxies = ('12 [' => '12 HealthStatus [',
               '520 [' => '520 A-SYNT [',
               '521 [' => '521 A-CONF [',
               '522 [' => '522 A-SAFE [',
               '12 ->' => '12 HealthStatus -> ');
my $proxies_match = join "|", map { quotemeta } keys %proxies;


while (<$in>) {
    s/$proxies_match/$proxies{$&}/g;
    print $out $_;
}
```

If `%proxies` only have those 4 keys though, the impact of speed will be negligible. And if `%proxies` have much more keys (and each of them is a number followed by either `->` or `[`), then this approach is a bit tedious.

Finally, Perl has a nice in-place file editing feature which can make you code a bit nicer to write, but this will depend on how large your script is (for a small script, it's probably ok; for a large one, it probably isn't):

```
$^I = '.bak'; # the extension for the backup file
              # This also will make "print" print into the input file
@ARGV = 't.txt'; # the file to be read when doing `<>`

my %proxies = ('12' => 'HealthStatus',
               '520' => ' A-SYNT',
               '521' => 'A-CONF',
               '522' => 'A-SAFE');

while (<>) {
    for my $proxy (keys %proxies) {
        s/(\Q$proxy\E) (\[|->)/$1 $proxies{$1} $2/g;
    }
    print;
}
```

Comment: Thanks A LOT! I was looping into myself =) I'm not very expert with Perl but the hint about the order of the loops resolved everything.

Comment: @gLiDeRJaCk happy to be of assistance! Of course you're free to reuse your old code and just fixing the order of the loops, but I strongly suggest that you take into account the 5 bullet points I've suggested, and in particular, always add `use strict; use warnings;` to your scripts ;-)

Comment: Obviously I'll take into account the 5 bullets (I'm still learning perl, I'm less than a novice) but at least now I'm out the cul-de-sac :)